# Listing profiles with Grails 3.3.1 throws org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException

Tags: grails, sdkman

I installed Grails 3.3.1 using SDKMAN!. Now I tried to list the available profiles using

```
grails list-profiles
```

and got the following error:

> | Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:4.0.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:4.0.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:319)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:121)
>       at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:134)
>       at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
>       at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.executeCommandWithArgumentValidation(GrailsCli.groovy:287)
>       at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:263)
>       at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
>   | Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:4.0.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core)

Do I have to change the repo?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the grails repo https://repo.grails.org/grails/core was down. When up, it returns list of the available artifacts and the above command should return a list of all available profiles as follows:

> ### grails list-profiles Resolving dependencies.. | Available Profiles
>
> - angular - A profile for creating Grails applications with Angular 2
> - rest-api - Profile for REST API applications
> - base - The base profile extended by other profiles
> - angularjs - A profile for creating applications using AngularJS
> - plugin - Profile for plugins designed to work across all profiles
> - profile - A profile for creating new Grails profiles
> - react - A profile for creating Grails applications with a React frontend
> - rest-api-plugin - Profile for REST API plugins
> - web - Profile for Web applications
> - web-jboss7 - A Profile for Creating a JBoss 7.1 EAP Project
> - web-plugin - Profile for Plugins designed for Web applications
> - webpack - A profile for creating applications with node-based frontends using webpack 2